# PHP-MySQL data is swapped after 'insert'

Tags: mysql

I have a strange problem.

I try to enter the following data in MySQL through a PHP-script:
1. arrival (date)
2. departure (date)
3. price (int, 11)

The PHP is the following:

```
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") 
{
    $errorMessage = "";

    if(empty($_POST['type'])) 
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>Gelieve een type in te voeren!</li>";
    }

    $hotel = $_POST['hotel'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $prijs = $_POST['prijs'];
    $arrival = $_POST['arrival'];
    $departure = $_POST['departure'];

    if(empty($errorMessage)) 
    {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO rooms (hotel, type, prijs, arrival, departure) VALUES (".
                        PrepSQL($hotel) . ", ".
                        PrepSQL($type) . ", ".
                        PrepSQL($arrival) . ", ".
                        PrepSQL($departure) . ", ".
                        PrepSQL($prijs) . ")";
        mysql_query($sql);          
        include("room-insert.php");
        exit();
    }
}


function PrepSQL($value)
{
    // Stripslashes
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
    {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }

    // Quote
    $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";

    return($value);
}
```

And the HTML is this:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">

        <tr>
        <p>
            <label for='hotel'>Hotel</label><br/>
            <input name="hotel" maxlength="50" value="<?=$naam;?>" />
        </p>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <p>
            <label for='type'>Type</label><br/>
            <input type="text" name="type" maxlength="50" value="<?=$type;?>" />
        </p>
        </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
        <td>
        <p>
            <label for='prijs'>Prijs</label><br/>
            <input type="text" name="prijs" maxlength="50" value="<?=$prijs;?>" />
        </p>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>
        <p>
            <label for='arrival'>Datum check-in</label><br/>
            <input type="date" name="arrival" maxlength="50" value="<?=$arrival;?>" />
        </p>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>
        <p>
            <label for='departure'>Datum check-out</label><br/>
            <input type="date" name="departure" maxlength="50" value="<?=$departure;?>" />
        </p>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
        </td>
        </tr>


    </form>
```

I enter this in the form:
Price (=prijs): 50
Arrival: 2012-09-12
Departure: 2012-09-30

This results like this in MySQL:

Price: 2012
Arrival: 2012-09-30
Departure: 50

So, completely messed up...

I tried several things, both in MySQL, PHP and HTML, all resulting in the same or worse and I'm now in a stage I have no more clue how this can be solved...

Thanks for your help!

Daan

Comment: Whatever `PrepSQL` is, which appears to be some kind of escape function, you should not be using `mysql_query` in new applications. You should be using `mysqli` or PDO and using [SQL statement placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to ensure your SQL escaping is done properly and consistently. Rolling your own SQL escaping is never a good idea. If you used named placeholders and `bind_param` this would never have happened.

Answer (score 0):

there is your buggy code:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO rooms (hotel, type, prijs, arrival, departure) VALUES (".
                        PrepSQL($hotel) . ", ".
                        PrepSQL($type) . ", ".
                        PrepSQL($arrival) . ", ".
                        PrepSQL($departure) . ", ".
                        PrepSQL($prijs) . ")";
```

You concatenate your variables in the wrong order, it should be like this:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO rooms (hotel, type, prijs, arrival, departure) VALUES (".
                        PrepSQL($hotel) . ", ".
                        PrepSQL($type) . ", ".
                        PrepSQL($prijs) . ")";
                        PrepSQL($arrival) . ", ".
                        PrepSQL($departure) . ", ".
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be in the INSERT SCRIPT section.

Try changing

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO rooms (hotel, type, prijs, arrival, departure) VALUES (". 
    PrepSQL($hotel) . ", ". 
    PrepSQL($type) . ", ". 
    PrepSQL($arrival) . ", ". 
    PrepSQL($departure) . ", ". 
    PrepSQL($prijs) . ")";
```

to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO rooms (hotel, type, prijs, arrival, departure) VALUES (". 
    PrepSQL($hotel) . ", ". 
    PrepSQL($type) . ", ". 
    PrepSQL($prijs) . ", ". 
    PrepSQL($arrival) . ", ". 
    PrepSQL($departure) . ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

You messed up the order of the values.

Your INSERT:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO rooms (hotel, type, prijs, arrival, departure) VALUES (".
                        PrepSQL($hotel) . ", ".
                        PrepSQL($type) . ", ".
                        PrepSQL($arrival) . ", ".
                        PrepSQL($departure) . ", ".
                        PrepSQL($prijs) . ")";
```

1. Hotel
2. Type
3. Price
4. Arrival
5. Departure

You insert the data in this order:

1. Hotel
2. Type
3. Arrival
4. Departure
5. Price